# Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient]:

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-directivas

Tengo el siguiente código en TypeScript, el problema se sitúa cuando al constructor le paso la variable `validarUsuario` me da este error en la consola del navegador:

> Error: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient]

¿Cual es la manera correcta de usar esa variable?

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
    import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';
    import { ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
    import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        routingComponents
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
            AppRoutingModule
          ],
          providers: [],
        })
        export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
          @ViewChild('ipId') span: ElementRef; 

          constructor(private router: Router /*,private validarUsuario: LoginService*/) { }
          public laRespuesta = [];
          ngOnInit() {
          }
          login(form: NgForm) {
            if (form.value.txtEmail === '' && form.value.txtPassword === '') {
              alert('Ingrese su usuario y contraseña');
              return;
            } else if (form.value.txtEmail === '') {
              alert('Ingrese su usuario');
              return;
            } else if ( form.value.txtPassword === '') {
              alert('Ingrese su contraseña');
              return;
            } else {
              let esint = false;
              const UrlSitio = window.location.href.toString();
              if (UrlSitio.search('localhost:4200')) {
                esint = true;
              } else {
                esint = false;
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: El servicio LoginService hace uso de Http? Si es así tienes que indicarlo en el módulo también.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El error te indica que no estás se encuentra el modulo de HTTP, que seguro estas utilizando en `LoginService`.

Tenés que importarlo a tu modulo, lo mejor que sea en tu archivo app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
// ..
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    // ...
  ]
 //...
```

De esta manera, en tu `LoginService` ya no habrá problema de que no encuentra `HttpClient`

Comment: amigo tengo un problema similar que no he podido resolver, podrías ayudarme?

Comment: Podés agregar una pregunta en stackoverflow y te ayudamos a responderla

Comment: Lo hice pero nadie me ha respondido, por eso entre tanta búsqueda y en medio de la desesperación decidí escribirte acá, este es el link:   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/391037/error-nullinjector-en-constructor-de-componente