# error nullinjector en constructor de componente

Tags: angular, constructor

Estoy tratando de trabajar con breakpoints en Angular, para esto uso el cdk.

En mi app.module.ts hago la respectiva importación así:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GuardGuard } from './accountVerification/guard/guard.guard';  
import { AuthInterceptorService } from './interceptors/auth-interceptor.service';

// import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { DragToSelectModule } from 'ngx-drag-to-select'; //api ngx-drag-to-select

//Modulos y servicios creados por mi 

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';
//import { EmailVerificationComponent } from './accountVerification/email-verification/email-verification.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home/home.component';
import { CheckEmailComponent } from './signinLogin/recovery-pass/new-pass/check-email/check-email.component';
import { PassConfirmComponent } from './signinLogin/recoveryPass/pass-confirm/pass-confirm.component';

import { SigninLoginModule } from './signinLogin/signin-login/signin-login.module';
//import { RecoveryPassComponent } from './signinLogin/recovery-pass/recovery-pass.component';

import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UploadImgComponent } from './upload-img/upload-img.component';
import {LayoutModule} from '@angular/cdk/layout';  // para usar breakpoints css directamente en Angular

//interceptors

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    //EmailVerificationComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CheckEmailComponent,
    PassConfirmComponent,
    UploadImgComponent,
    //RecoveryPassComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SigninLoginModule,
    FormsModule,
    DragToSelectModule.forRoot(),
    LayoutModule
  ], 
  
  .
  .
  .
```

Luego... para usar mis propias medidas y evitar sobrescribir las del cdk, tengo estos 2 servicios:

1. breakpoints.service:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class BreakpointsService {
  breakpoints: object = {
    '(max-width: 220px)': CustomBreakpointNames.extraSmall,
    '(min-width: 2400px)': CustomBreakpointNames.extraLarge
  };

  getBreakpoints(): string[] {
    return Object.keys(this.breakpoints);
  }

  getBreakpointName(breakpointValue): string {
    return this.breakpoints[breakpointValue];
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}

export const CustomBreakpointNames = {
  extraSmall: 'extraSmall',
  extraLarge: 'extraLarge'
};
```

2. layout.service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BreakpointObserver} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import {BreakpointsService} from './breakpoints.service';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LayoutService {

    activeBreakpoints: string[] = [];

    constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private breakpointService: BreakpointsService) { }

    subscribeToLayoutChanges(): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.breakpointObserver
          .observe(this.breakpointService.getBreakpoints())
          .pipe(map((observeResponse) => this.parseBreakpointsResponse(observeResponse.breakpoints)));
    }

    parseBreakpointsResponse(breakpoints): string[] {
    
        this.activeBreakpoints = [];

        Object.keys(breakpoints).map((key) => {
          if (breakpoints[key]) {
            this.activeBreakpoints.push(this.breakpointService.getBreakpointName(key));
          }
        });

        return this.activeBreakpoints;
    }

    isBreakpointActive(breakpointName) {
        return this.activeBreakpoints.find(breakpoint => breakpoint === breakpointName);
    }

}
```

Por último, acá está el componente (upload-img) donde utilizo como tal los breakpoints, en el oninit es donde iba a llamar al método, lo tengo comentado solo por cuestiones de prueba, solo con hacer la importación arriba me marca ese error.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { LayoutService } from '../layout.service' ;
import {CustomBreakpointNames} from '../breakpoints.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-img',
  templateUrl: './upload-img.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-img.component.css']
})
export class UploadImgComponent implements OnInit {
    imgLoader: boolean;
    images= [];
    selected: any[]= [];
    imgName: string='';
    pos: number= -1;
    height: string;

  constructor(private layoutService: LayoutService) {  }
 
  // formulario para el primer boton "cargar fotos"
  imgUploadForm = new FormGroup({
    file: new FormControl('',[Validators.required])


  });

  // formulario para el segundo botón "agregar fotos" de la segunda vista
  imgUploadForm2 = new FormGroup({
    file2: new FormControl('',[Validators.required])


  });

  ngOnInit(): {
    // this.layoutService.subscribeToLayoutChanges()
    //  .subscribe(observerResponse => {
       //   console.log('\nPreguntando si la resolucion es extraSmall...\n')
          //   // You will have all matched breakpoints in observerResponse
          //   if (this.layoutService.isBreakpointActive(CustomBreakpointNames.extraSmall)) {
          //    console.log('\nSi es extraSmall...\n')
          //        this.height= window.innerHeight.toString();
        //          this.height= this.height+'px';
          //    // Do something here for extraSmall devices
          //   }
    // });

    //console.log('\nMOSTRANDO innerHeight ---> \n'+this.height )
  }
  
  .
  .
  .
  .
```

cabe destacar, que ese componente lo llamo desde el componente padre (html.component), el cuál es este:

```js
<div *ngIf="!imgUpload; else componentUpload" class="home">
    <!-- <img src="../../assets/white.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"> -->

    <div class="cover-page-cont" >
        <div id="cont-img">
            <img class="img-cover-page img-fluid" src="{{coverImg}}" alt="">            
        </div>
        <div id="cont-info" class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div id="img-perfil">
                <img src="{{profileImg}}" alt="imagen de perfil">               
            </div>
            <div class="ml-3">
                <p class="subtitulo" >{{names}} {{lastNames}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <button (click)="getUser()"> Obtener Usuarios </button> -->

    <div id="images-cont" class="pt-5">
        <div *ngIf="existImages()" class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p class="text-big text-center"> Aún no has subido fotos. </p>
                <p class="text-med text-center"> Tu galería está vacía. ¡Anímate y sube algunas fotos! </p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8 col-sm-4 text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary button-responsive" (click)="changeImgUploadValue()">  Cargar Fotos </button>
            </div>
        </div>


<!--        <div id="camera-img">
            <img src="../../../assets/camera-roll.png" alt="imagen de cámara">
        </div> -->
    </div>


</div>

<ng-template #componentUpload> 

    <app-upload-img>  </app-upload-img> *** ESTA ES LA LÍNEA 44 A LA QUE HACE REFERENCIA EL ERROR (html.component)  <!-- AQUI LLAMO AL COMPONENTE UPLOAD-IMG QUE ES DONDE UTILIZO LOS BREAKPOINTS -->

</ng-template>
```

acá muestro una captura del error que me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puede estar pasando? si en el componente (upload-img) quito la inyección del `servicio LayoutService` el error desaparece, es como si BreakpointObserver no se estuviera importando, ya busqué algo relacionado, pero nada me sirvió. Intenté colocando el servicio layout.service (que es dónde importo el BreakpointObserver) en los providers del AppModule y no sirvió, el componente está importado directamente en el App.module (me refiero a que no hay un módulo de por medio), ya no se que más intentar. Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar,

Saludos!

Comment: Hola que tal, puedes compartir tus versiones de angular y angular material? Además de el código en HomeComponent.html:44? gracias.

Comment: mi versión de angular es: 8.2.14 y lo que instalé fué el cdk con el comando: ``` npm i @angular/cdk ``` , la versión que se instaló fue: 6.11.2

Comment: Entonces probablemente ese es el problema, intenta instalar la [version 8.2.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cdk/v/8.2.3) del cdk.

Comment: @OscarLudick Hola amigo, si me funcionó instalando el cdk desde ese link que me pasaste. Aunque antes de instalarla, para saber que versión tenía lo hice con el siguiente comando ```npm @angular/cdk -v``` y me arrojaba 6.11.2 , ahora... luego de instalar la versión que me pasaste, vuelvo a ejecutar el comando y me sigue arrojando 6.11.2 . por que será? o estoy ejecutando el comando incorrecto ?

Comment: Hola, intenta instalando nuevamente la versión pero esta vez con la bandera --save `npm i @angular/cdk@8.2.3 --save` y después checa que tu dependencia se encuentre actualizada con la versión correcta en tu package.json o con el comando `npm list --depth=0`

Comment: @OscarLudick En el package.json si aparece ```@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3"``` , será que el comando ```npm @angular/cdk -v``` no es el correcto ? cuándo lo ejecuto me devuelve ```6.11.2``` no se entonces a que refiere eso. Bueno en fin... tu respuesta me funcionó, me gustaría poder calificarte ya que fuiste el único que se tomó el tiempo para ayudarme.

Comment: Oh ya, quiero suponer que el comando npm @angular/cdk -v , no esta tomando realmente el nombre de la librería, lo omite, te esta regresando la versión de npm. Si ejecutas `npm -v` te debería regresar la misma versión 6.11.2, así compruebas que esta omitiendo el @angular/cdk y no te preocupes amigo, para eso estamos.

Comment: @OscarLudick Hola amigo. de nuevo por acá. resulta que creé otro proyecto donde quiero usar flex-layout, instalé tanto el cdk como flex layout con el sgte comando: ```npm i -s @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk``` en el package.json tengo: ```"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.2"``` y ```"@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32"``` pero recibo este error ahora:  ``` NullInjectorError: No provider for StyleUtils!````mi versión de angular es ```8.2.3``` y necesito trabajar con angular 8 si o si. que podría hacer para resolverlo ?

Comment: Ya lo resolví. el problema que veo es que cuándo instalas un paquete, se te instala automáticamente la última versión de éste. En este caso la última versión del cdk y flex-layout es 10, y siempre las versiones de los paquetes deben coincidir con la versión de angular (en este caso mi versión es 8.2.14) lo cuál no era mi caso. tuve que instalar la versión 8.2.1 del cdk y la versión 8.0.0-beta.26 de flex-layout.